# SQL Inner Join returns duplicates

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have the following 2 tables:

`tab1` with  37146 rows
[image: table1]

`week_ref` with 730 rows

[image: table2]

All I want to do is join those tables on year and week so that the first week day and last week day will display next to the columns of the first table.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT tab1.year
      ,tab1.week
      ,tab1.col3
      ,tab1.col4
      ,tab1.col5
      ,tab1.col6
      ,tab1.total
      ,tab1.col7
      ,week_ref.first_week_day
      ,week_ref.last_week_day
      
FROM dtsetname.tab1

JOIN spyros.week_ref ON (week_ref.year = tab1.year AND week_ref.week = tab1.week)
```

The return of the query returns the 2 extra columns but the rows are 255535. So it is full of duplicates. I used to get how join works, but I guess not anymore xd... Any help on this? The correct output table should only give me 37146 rows since I only just want to add 2 extra columns.

Thanks

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS "full of duplicates" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Before JOIN'ing you just need to dedup data in week_ref table as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT tab1.year
      ,tab1.week
      ,tab1.col3
      ,tab1.col4
      ,tab1.col5
      ,tab1.col6
      ,tab1.total
      ,tab1.col7
      ,week_ref.first_week_day
      ,week_ref.last_week_day
FROM dtsetname.tab1 tab1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT year, week, first_week_day, last_week_day FROM spyros.week_ref) week_ref
ON (week_ref.year = tab1.year AND week_ref.week = tab1.week)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `week_ref` table has a row for each day rather than per week.

You can select just one day.  If you have a weekday number or name (which I'm guessing that you do), that can be used:

```
FROM dtsetname.tab1 JOIN
     spyros.week_ref wr
     ON wr.year = tab1.year AND
        wr.week = tab1.week AND
        wr.dayname = 'Monday'
```

If such a column is not available, then you can either `extract()` the information or aggregate:

```
FROM dtsetname.tab1 JOIN
     (SELECT ANY_VALUE(wr).*
      FROM spyros.week_ref wr
      GROUP BY wr.year, wr.week
     ) wr
     ON wr.year = tab1.year AND
        wr.week = tab1.week
```

Comment: I'd also recommend having the raw dates in a separate table from the table which specifies the start and end range.  It would help avoid/simplify problems like this.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the error. I ended up doing something else.

Comment: @Lev . . . Mikhail's answer is equivalent to this one and he answered 10 minutes later.  May I ask why you accepted that answer rather than this one?

Comment: Hey, you were right about the mistake. I didn't use the first block of code you gave because I didn't have day, but for the second block you suggested, I don't know if it's the same but it seemed more clear in Mikhail's answer and when I read all the answers this is what I could understand faster. If yours is better or not, you got more experience so you can tell. I just picked based on what I understood the easiest. You've helped me tons of times and I don't have something against anyone in the community when choosing answers.

Comment: @Lev . . . That's fine.  I should have added that as the OP you can accept any answer you like.  I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

first, I hope that year+week & year+day are primary keys in corresponding tables, otherwise the problem is there.

If so, here is another hint to check:
I notice that you join them by year and week, however, in the first table I see many 52 in a week column and in the second one 0 as a value.

There are only 52 weeks in year, plus a day, so is it possible you need to join by

```
week_ref.year = tab1.year AND week_ref.week = tab1.week+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solutions mentioned by others should work if you are looking to join to your reference table to get week start/end dates.

However, if you think your `tab1` table has definite values in the `week` and `year` columns (and if I understand your data correctly) you can *avoid the join altogether* to get your desired results:

```
select 
  year
  ,week
  ,col3
  ,col4
  ,col5
  ,col6
  ,total
  ,col7
  ,date_sub(weekdate, interval IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM weekdate) = 1, 6, EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM weekdate) - 1) day) as first_week_day
  ,date_add(date_sub(weekdate, interval IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM weekdate) = 1, 6, EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM weekdate) - 1) day), interval 6 day) as last_week_day
from (  
  select 
     tab1.year
    ,tab1.week
    ,tab1.col3
    ,tab1.col4
    ,tab1.col5
    ,tab1.col6
    ,tab1.total
    ,tab1.col7
    date_add(date(cast(tab1.year as int64), 1, 1), interval cast(tab1.week as int64) week) as weekdate
  from `mydataset.tab1` as tab1
)
```

Hope it helps :)